# :wrapper_tag, :wrapper_class options (and more) with simple_form and Rails 2.3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm making my first Rails project and I'm using the simple_form gem (version 1.0) with a Rails app (version 2.3.5).
[simple_form repository v=1.0](http://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/tree/v1.0)

Is there any way to implement the nice options :wrapper_tag, :wrapper_class, :wrapper_error_class ? Or maybe I'm missing something? :-D

Thank you for your advices

Fro_oo

ps : I can't change my Rails gem and upgrade to a 3.x version...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer come from carlosantoniodasilva:

After running simple_form_install generator you'll get all available configurations. It's possible to change the wrapper_tag, as you can see here:
http://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/v1.0/generators/simple_form_install/templates/simple_form.rb#L17

You can also add options to wrapper tag specifically for each attribute by passing :wrapper_html => { :foo => 'bar' }.

Other options aren't available.